# Caching website by Codeigniter or 3rd party caching web application?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, caching, html

I'm very new to the concept "caching", so excuse me if my question is too simple.
So,I'm using Codeigniter(PHP framework) and it supports page caching, simply by doing this `$this->output->cache(n)//n: number of minutes to remain cached`
(I think) Codeigniter's caching will store any requested page in a cache file, and get the page when needed immediately.
Also there's a 3rd part web application called [Vanish Cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/about), it sits between Apache and the client, then it will cache requested pages and re-send them again when needed, isn't that the same thing Codeigniter does, or is it different from that?
Wouldn't it be a waste to cache each page twice, by Codeigniter and Vanish?

assuming they do the exact same thing(cache pages and re-send them to the user),which one is *more* efficient for dynamic(database driver) websites?

Comment: use html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740799/meta-expires-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the surface, they do the same thing, however there are appropriate uses for different levels of cache.

A cache like Varnish, that sits between the web server and the application, provides very high performance. You use it for static content like CSS, static pages and dynamic content that changes very rarely.

An application cache provides a less performant but far more flexibile option. Usually you can cache by time, but also by application/request variables like "current user". This allows you to provide an *state-dependant* cache with a lot more fine control. For example, you could cache an object's detail page by it's last modified time in the database.

Comment: So, I shouldn't active both of them at the same time?

Comment: They are suitable for different situations, so yes you can have both working. you wouldn't cache the *same* content with both, though.